# Iterate through a list using index?

Tags: python

**Code**

```
list_ = [1, 2, 3, 4]
sum_ = 0
for list_[-1] in list_:
    print(list_[-1])
    sum_ += list_[-1]
print("sum: ", sum_)
```

**Output**

```
1
2
3
3
sum: 9
```

Can someone explain how this for loop works?

Comment: That code (which is awful) does not produce that output.

Comment: @JohnColeman it actually does.

Comment: It is surprising that the code as written isn't a syntax error. Somewhat strangely, `list[-1]` has type `<class 'types.GenericAlias'>`

Comment: @Bharel perhaps it does if `list[-1]` (in their code) is replaced by `list_[-1]`. If you simply copy-paste their code and run it, it doesn't have that output. It has a truly bizarre output instead.

Comment: @JohnColeman yeah I fixed it. I guess that's what the op meant. Regarding the generic alias, yeah it's used for the static type checking. Almost all built in container types can be subscripted.

Answer (score 1):

Every item replaced the item in the last position. You then print the item in the last position. `-2` is repeated twice because it is in the position before last, and in the last.

Keep in mind you have 2 typos while referring to the list. I fixed them.